# How to fix sonar issue squid:ForLoopCounterChangedCheck?

Tags: java, sonarqube

My code was detected by sonar with violation **"for" loop stop conditions should be invariant.**
I tried to fix it but sonar thinks the issue is still there because my for-loop is inside another for-loop.

Here's the code snippet:

```
int limit = Const.getBatchLimit();
int count = 0;

for (int paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < paramList.size();)
{
    List<Param> tempParam = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder retrieveMsg = new StringBuilder("Retrieving: \n");
    for (count = 0; (count < limit) && (paramIndex < param.size()); count++, paramIndex++)
    {
        Param myParam = paramList.get(paramIndex);
        retrieveMsg.append(myParam .seq()).append(Str.SLASH).append(Str.CRLF);
        tempParam.add(myParam);
    }
    LOGGER.info(retrieveMsg.toString());

    LOGGER.info("Done. Retrieved count: " + tempParam.size());
}
```

I can't move paramIndex++ up to the first for-loop because the behavior will be different from what is desired.

Appreciate it if someone can give advice on how to fix this violation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting way to split parameter list into chunks of `limit` size but it may be possible to get rid of the nested loop at all.

Also, if `tempParam` is used only to track the number of elements in the batch, it may be replaced by reusing `count`.

```java
int limit = Const.getBatchLimit();

StringBuilder retrieveMsg = new StringBuilder("Retrieving: \n");

for (int i = 0, count = 1, n = paramList.size(); i < n; i++, count++) {
    Param myParam = paramList.get(i);
    retrieveMsg.append(myParam.seq()).append(Str.SLASH).append(Str.CRLF);

    if (count % limit == 0 || i == n - 1) {
        LOGGER.info(retrieveMsg.toString());
        LOGGER.info("Done. Retrieved count: " + count);
        retrieveMsg = new StringBuilder("Retrieving: \n");
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Or this code could be completely refactored to use Java Stream API and implementing a helper method to handle the chunk (e.g. `printChunk`):

```java
int chunks = paramList.size() / limit + (paramList.size() % limit == 0 ? 0 : 1);
IntStream.range(0, chunks)
         .mapToObj(i -> paramList.subList(i * limit, Math.min((i + 1) * limit, paramList.size()))) // getting stream of sublists
         .forEach(MyClass::printChunk);

// ...
static void printChunk(List<Param> chunk) {
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("Retrieving:\n");
    chunk.forEach(p -> msg.append(p.seq()).append(Str.SLASH).append(Str.CRLF));

    LOGGER.info(msg.toString());
    LOGGER.info("Done. Retrieved count: " + chunk.size());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. will try it out and let you know what works.

Comment: tried your first suggestion and it worked. thanks again.